# Как отобразить русский текст?

Tags: windows, сокет, c++

Перехватываю пакет, и там иногда бывает текст на английском, а иногда - на русском. С английским проблем нету, отображается хорошо, а вот что с русским делать?

Как узнать русский или английский текст и как потом отобразить русский?

Comment: А еще лучше не мучатся и уйти с винды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо знать кодировку текста, например, она может быть указана в Content-Type http-заголовке и/или в xml-декларации и/или как `<meta charset="utf-8">` внутри html-документа и т.д. Если данные из файла, то некоторые кодировки (utf-8, utf-16, utf-32) позволяют указывать BOM (специальная метка в начале файла). В худшем случае, существуют библиотеки такие как chardet, которые пытаются угадать кодировку по содержимому (это не всегда можно точно сделать).

Нельзя содержимое называть текстом, если не известна его кодировка. [Абсолютный Минимум, который Каждый Разработчик Программного Обеспечения Обязательно Должен Знать о Unicode и Наборах Символов](http://goo.gl/z0hfQU)

**Обновление**

Если кодировка текста известна, то шаг номер два: превратить байты в Юникодный текст. Для некоторых кодировок можно использовать `MultiByteToWideChar()`. Шаг номер три: отобразить Юникод. Для печати в консоль, можно использовать `WriteConsoleW()` или `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); wprintf(L"%s\n", unicode_text);` (printf, cout, wcout не должны использоваться в последнем варианте). Чтобы буквы были видны в консоли, нужно создать ярлык для приложения и настроить в нём шрифт (например, Lucida console) и запускать программу через ярлык. При печати в файл (и `type`) можно BOM добавить.

Вот [полный пример кода из msdn как напечатать Юникод текст в Виндовую консоль с `cmd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"\x043a\x043e\x0448\x043a\x0430 \x65e5\x672c\x56fd\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Повторюсь: это решение *не совместимо* с `printf()`. Не нужно вызывать SetConsoleCP или SetConsoleOutputCP c вышеприведённым кодом. Единственное что нужно, чтобы (TrueType) шрифт был настроен в консоле (такой как Lucida Console).

Comment: Плюсую @jfs, в свое время именно эта статья расставила у меня точки над i.

Comment: перепробовал разные комбинации(шрифт тоже ставил разный), но русского так и не получил, разве что кракозябры менялись по виду. Вот один из вариантов как я делал :  

     if(data[0] > 0x7f)
    {
     wchar_t tmp_wstr[sizeof(data)];
     MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, (char*)data, sizeof(data), tmp_wstr, sizeof(data));
     wprintf(L"UTF8 :%s", tmp_wstr);
    }
    else
     printf("ANSI : %s\n", data);

Comment: Вообщем сделал, но какое-то плохое решение.

 SetConsoleCP(65001);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

И шрифт Lucida Console

Comment: @xinakapu не нужно использовать `(data[0] > 0x7f)`. `data` или является текстом, закодированным в utf-8, или нет. Я добавил пример с `wprintf()`. Если русские буквы видны нормально в выводе примера, то можно дальше двигаться. `MultiByteToWideChar()` нужно по-другому использовать: см. [utf8_decode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3999597).

Answer (score 1):

> Как узнать русский или английский текст и как потом отобразить русский?

Русские (точнее, нелатинские) символы всегда будут кодироваться одни байтом со значением > 127 в однобайтовой кодировке и секвенцией, начинающейся с байта со значением > 127 в utf-8 (подробнее в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B8_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0_.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.B2_UTF-8)).

В целом задача сводится к определению кодировки, и если определить utf-8/utf-16/utf-32 еще представляется возможным вручную, то с остальным зоопарком требуется сидеть со стат анализом и подбирать наиболее подходящую кодировку.

Comment: @Etki, на свежую голову почитаю). Кстати, только что попробовал в файл записывать, и в нем английский и русский нормально отображаются, а в консоли нет. При этом стоит setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUSSIAN") и если просто текст выводить скажем так printf("текст"), то все нормально, а если printf("текст%s", data), то выведется только "текст", а дальше кракозябры, то есть кракозябры в консоль и нормальный текст в файл. Можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @Etki

> Русские (точнее, нелатинские) символы всегда будут кодироваться одни байтом со значением > 127

не совсем правда. [КОИ-7](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%98-7), к примеру, никто не отменял.