# Ввод русских букв из консоли в переменную в C (Windows)

Tags: c, windows

Как осуществляется ввод пользователем русских символов из консоли в переменную под Windows?

При использовании `gets()` программа вылетает с ошибкой. `scanf()` не выдаёт русский символ. Для теста использую такую программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    char ch;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("%c", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Интересует решение именно в C, а не C++.

Comment: Точно так же, как и любых символов. Хотите `gets`, хотите `scanf`.

Comment: @PashaPash Вопрос касается именно C, а не C++.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Ни то, ни другое корректно не работает с русскими символами. Изменил вопрос в соответствии с результатами попыток.

Comment: @MaxRogers Ну как минимум char - это 1 байт, а сейчас повсеместно UTF-8, в котором Русские символы 2х байтовые.

Comment: @MaxRogers я понимаю что этот вопрос про С, но поддержка юниода в консоли - это платформозависимая вещь. решение `_setmode` по ссылке - это решение прежде всего для C, а для C++ оно срабатывает только из-за общего кода работы с консолью :)

Comment: @MaxRogers, Судя по симптомам, у вас установлена кодировка 65001 (UTF-8), поэтому русский символ представляется двумя байтами. Вы должны либо использовать однобайтную кодировку 1251, либо использовать не тип `char`, а тип `wchar_t` и поле `%C` или `%lc` вместо `%c`.

Comment: Уточните, какую оболочку используете (cmd, PowerShell), какие кодировки (например, что `chcp` выводит). Какие версии Windows интересуют? Если возникает ошибка, то как её воспроизвести: что ввести в консоле, что в результате видете, что хотите вместо этого видеть? Вот [похожий вопрос (но про вывод, а не ввод)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044): добейтесь, чтобы код с  `wprintf()` заработал в вашем окружении, затем попробуйте `wscanf()` для ввода.