# Как вывести русский текст в консоль

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, mingw

Есть UTF-8 строка с русским текстом: `"\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x82"`.

Надо вывести ее на консоль так, чтобы это работало на следующих трех платформах и компиляторах:

- Windows и VC++,
- Windows и MinGW,
- Linux и gcc.

Предполагается что шрифт консоли позволяет показать хотя бы русские буквы.

Следует обратить внимание на то, что в MinGW локали реализованы не полностью, и многие решения для VC++ не будут работать.
MinGW можно взять [здесь](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Можно использовать `#ifdef`. Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, например Boost.

---

Вот пример решения дня MinGW, но **нужна поддержка всех трех платформ**.

```
> type main.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>, wchar_t> conv;
    std::wstring ws = conv.from_bytes("[test \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 \xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88]\n");
    DWORD _; ::WriteConsoleW(::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ws.c_str(), ws.size(), &_, nullptr);
}

> g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && a
[test тест テスト]
```

Comment: Для MSVC, кажется, полноценный работающий вариант — только перевод в UTF-16. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105 (но там рассматривается и ввод, и не только русский текст, а вообще Unicode)

Comment: Я что-то сомневаюсь в достижимости. У меня не получилось подружить виндушную консоль с utf-8. Разве что `#ifdef _MSCVER` + особый код для винды.

Comment: Но цель благая, да.

Comment: Кстати, а есть ли решение для MinGW? Оно тоже должно дружить с виндоконсолью.

Comment: Ну, это решение покатит и для MSVC. Имея `wstring`, можно воспользоваться кодом из вопроса по ссылке из первого комментария. Выводить просто через `wcout`. (Интересно, а покатит ли то решение для MinGW?)

Comment: А широкий `wcout`?

Comment: Странно. А если произнести магическое заклинание `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`?

Comment: Как насчет использования библиотеки Qt и её класса QString с функцией toLocal8Bit() ? Если не нужны зависимости, можно хотя бы посмотреть имплементацию в исходниках.

Comment: Лучше в сторону многобайтовой кодировки смотреть. Память нынче почти бесплатная, можно не экономить, а удобство налицо.

Comment: Вот рабочий код на Windows: [Как отобразить русский текст?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044). На Linux, `setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); std::wcout << L"\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442";`, если хочется локаль поддерживать, но это сломается если локаль не сконфигурирована (С). На \*nix в большинстве случаев лучше просто utf-8 кодировку  поддерживать. Посмотрите как [`Boost.NoWide` библиотека реализована](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/): на Винде WriteFile/WriteConsoleW используются, на других системах просто utf-8 строчки используйте: `std::cout << "текст \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442"`

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека Qt (достаточно Core) кроссплатформенная и собирается любым компилятором. Вариант вывода в консоль:

```
QString string = QString::fromUtf8("Привет мир !");

// для консоли Windows
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
// для Linux
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("System");

QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(string);
std::cout << encodedString.data();
```

[Список поддерживаемых Qt кодеков](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html)

Comment: И позволяет ли это выводить символы на других языках?

Comment: Я не проверял, но ваш вопрос не раз решался в Интернете для Windows и Qt. Для Linux это точно работает. Текущую кодировку консоли можно вытащить из WinAPI (`GetConsoleCP`). На счет всех других возможных языков я сказать не могу. 

Ещё одно решение:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766301/windows-console-and-qt-unicode-text

Comment: Про самоответы: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2393/.