# C++ вывод "галочки" на экран

Tags: c++

Как вывести с помощью `std::cout << ("") << std::endl;` галочку на экран.

Comment: О какой "галочке" речь?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подобии такой, как мы получаем при `setChecked(true);` -> http://artgorbunov.ru/projects/galochki/arial.png

Comment: Коды символов 0xFB, 0xBB пробуйте

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to print Unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12015571/4279)

Comment: Туда же: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: тут о русских символов речи нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
cout <<  "\u2713" <<endl;
```

Или другие галочки по ссылке: [Галочка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Почти наверняка это не будет работать в Windows консоли. Какая кодировка у `"\u2713"` строки получается? (зависит ли она от компилятора? настроек IDE?)

Answer (score 7):

Мой искренний совет: поскольку вывод на консоль зависит от массы факторов - широкие символы используются или нет, кодировка и т.п. - не заморачивайтесь, а воспользуйтесь чем-то похожим. Ну кой смысл в консоли эту красоту наводить? :)

Выведите какую-нибудь `v`, которая везде будет одинакова - ведь вряд ли вы ее с буквой перепутаете.

Comment: Ну, консоль, это только для теста... а так, все будет выводится в PDF файле :)

Comment: Ну, для теста точно сойдет :) Как вам вариант - `[v]` или `[ ]`?

Comment: Тоже не плохо, нужно будет подумать :)

Answer (score 4):

Галочка может быть представлена Unicode символом [✓(U+2713)](https://codepoints.net/U+2713). В этом случае ваш вопрос сводится: «как вывести Юникод на экран в c++», что может зависеть от платформы.

На Windows, чтобы произвольные символы выводить в консоль, не смотря на текущую codepage, можно использовать `WriteConsoleW()` API или эквивалент (`_O_U16TEXT` режим и `wprintf()` c `wchar_t` строками, см. [Как отобразить русский текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044)). Необходимо выставить шрифт в консоли, который способен `✓` отображать. Ковыряние с locale или `SetConsoleOutputCP()` не помогут с Unicode в общем случае.

На других системах, можно просто utf-8 выводить (предполагая, что терминал использует utf-8), [например в c++11](http://ideone.com/yJkrBu):

```
cout << u8"\u2713";
```

Можно `boost::nowide::cout` использовать для переносимости: [utf-8 строки автоматически декодируются и используется `WriteConsoleW()` за кадром, если необходимо](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/index.html#technical_cio).