# Ввод/вывод кириллицы в консоли Windows

Tags: c++, windows, кодировка

Работал на *Linux*, проблем с кодировками не было вовсе. Нужно было теперь работать на *Windows*.

Всё вроде хорошо, но не было русских символов, одни кракозябры. Менялись на другие при:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Копался в реестре, менял шрифт консоли, в общем всё что есть адекватное в *Google*. После я решил случайно изменить `SetConsoleCP(1251);` на `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);`(конечно и `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`).

Радости было много, родной язык в консоли. Но прошло пару дней и теперь надо вводить ещё русский, но программа сразу ложится. Судя по отладчику строка поступает просто пустая.

Как можно исправить это?

Comment: перефразируйте задачу, немног не ясно что у вас не получается, ну и на код посомтреть бы.

Comment: а чем чтение то происходит с консоли и в какую переменную?

Comment: По поводу кода. Самая обычная строка. просто создал str = new char [80]. cin >> str; И всё, программа крашится. Но если например str = "Привет мир!", и cout << str, то она выведет Привет мир!.
В общем вывод работает, а ввод русских символов нет.

Comment: не в char нужно считывать, а в wchar_t.

Comment: Можно подробнее? Почему так? Нас в универе учат char, а почему надо wchar_t????

Comment: потому что в консоле указано UTF-8, а это 2 байтовая кодировка

Comment: в винде, в отличие от линуха по стандарту несколько кодировок одновременно могут использоваться. Из однобайтных - cp866 стандартно в консоле. Если хочется работать с char то преобразовывать нужно. Внутри IDE скорей всего utf-8. Вот и пляшем. В линукс, одна кодировка на консоль и гуи, если специально кто то не извратился

Comment: Спасибо, это я уже прочел на разных форумах, но как всё же сделать чтобы ввод работал? Вывод заработал, как только указал utf-8, а вот ввод не работает, я не знаю как это исправить. Я понял, что можно заменить char на wchar_t, но а есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: c wchar_t работает ввод? (ну и конечно, лучше использовать `std::wcout` и `std::wcin`).

Comment: А объяснить это может кто-нибудь?) Ребят, оно приятно что работает, Спасибо! Но хотелось бы узнать почему. Просто преподаватель будет спрашивать почему так, а я сам не знаю даже..

Comment: в тексте программы utf-8, консоль UTF-8, все работает с выводом и вводом. Двухбайтная кодировка. Если указать 866, то можно и однобайтовую с char. Но тогда текст вывода из программы нужно преобразовать в cp866

Comment: SetConsoleCP(866);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(866); Что-то кроказябрый..( Может надо ещё файлы исходного кода сохранять тоже в 866

Comment: @maint, UTF-8 это многобайтовая кодировка, а не двубайтовая и `wchar_t` там не то, что не поможет, он там вообще никак не нужен.

Comment: А Вам он нужен, русский язык в консоли? Если да, то приготовьтесь к массе проблем. Просто и универсально в C++ эта задача не решается.

Comment: Мне лично надо курсовую сдать, перподу надо на русском вводить текст, соответственно и выводить. Курсовая простая, там просто строки. Но из-за того что у меня qt куча проблем, у одногруппников вижла и проблем нету. Мне нужно это как то исправить убил уже в сумме час 6 на эту проблему, решился написать сюда.

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/Русский-язык-в-консоли/459299#459299) ответ. Там, в целом, есть всё, чтобы Вам можно было сделать рабочее решение.

Comment: @Fridreman: Вижу, что вы используете Qt, переоткрыл вопрос. Но всё же, я бы порекомендовал просто перейти на Visual Studio.

Comment: Забудьте о `SetConsoleCP()` и тому подобных костылях. Если на Linux с utf-8 char-строками всё работало, то попробуйте `boost::nowide::cin` (должно `ReadConsoleW()` вызвать за кадром в консоли). Связанный вопрос: [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте кодировку компилируемых файлов *.cpp, они должны быть в той кодировке в которой вы выводите текст.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно ответить только кодом:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода

    char string[20];
    cin >> string; // вводим строку, используя Кириллицу
    cout << "\nвывод: "<< string << endl; // ввывод строки
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[ссылка на источник](http://cppstudio.com/post/435/)

Ну и советую в настройках консоли поменять шрифт на luicida console плюс использовать cp1251 кодировку формата файла с исходным кодом (поскольку это виндовс)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]