# Программа не принимает русский ввод

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

При вводе в if условия на русском программа не выводит код дальше

```
cout << "Выбери действие:\nсложение/вычитание/умножение/деление/выход\n\n";
cin >> menu;
cout << "\n------------------------------------\n";
if (menu == "сложение") {
    cout << "Первое число:\n\n";
    cin >> uix;
    cout << "\nВторое число:\n\n";
    cin >> uiy;
    cout << "\nПолученное число: " << uix + uiy << endl;
```

а вот если заменить на английский:

```
if (menu == "sometext")
```

программа выводит то, что нужно.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего `uix + uiy` вам нужно преобразовать в строку.

Comment: nick_n_a, нет, я про условие в if.

Comment: А что у вас в этот момент реально в `menu`?

Answer (score 2):

Несоответствие кодировок. Если вы в Windows - мой совет: просто работайте в 866 кодировке, соответственно, набирая в ней и сам код программы.

Дело в том, что программы обычно - в 1251 кодировке Windows, а консоль - в 866 кодировке.

Еще вариант - попробуйте запустить перед началом работы консоли команду `chcp 1251`. Например, первой строчкой после `int main()` - `system("chcp 1251")`...

Вот еще - смотрите, например, тут:

[Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

[Ввод/вывод кириллицы в консоли Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579015/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-windows)

Comment: Ну, эээ, 866 — ужасно, потому что (1) большинство Windows-приложений (редакторов кода) её не знают, и (2) она плохо умеет родственные языки (украинский/белорусский), и (3) совсем не умеет английскую диакритику (café, crème brûlée, El Niño, naïveté и т. д.) Не тащите ТС в прошлый век!

Comment: @VladD Ну, я сам из прошлого века :), и если уж нужен русский в консоли - предпочитаю именно этот способ. Конечно, не навязываю. Так сказать, в качестве **PS** - а вообще это ж додуматься - использовать одновременно две разные кодировки...

Comment: У Windows одна кодировка для кириллицы — CP1251. Консоль использует древнюю кодировку CP866 для совместимости с прошлым веком, но никто ж из пользователей Windows не использует консоль.

Comment: @VladD Тогда откуда вопрос ТС? :) Вот как минимум уже один человек есть...

Comment: ТС не пользователь, ТС программист. Пользователи не пользуются консолью :) А программисты должны страдать за то, чтобы пользователям было удобнее :-D

Answer (score 0):

Этот пример работает.
Кодировка .cpp файла, т.е. и кириллических строк - 866 (OEM русская)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
string  menu;
int uix, uiy;
cout << cout << "Выбери действие:\nсложение/вычитание/умножение/деление/выход\n\n";
    cin >> menu;
    cout << "\n------------------------------------\n";
    if (menu == "сложение") {
        cout << "Первое число:\n\n";
        cin >> uix;
        cout << "\nВторое число:\n\n";
        cin >> uiy;
        cout << "\nПолученное число: " << uix + uiy << endl;
     }   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создай новый исходный (*.cpp) файл в свой проект, скопируй туда вот это содержимое:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wincon.h>

#define MAX_STRLEN  256

std::string FormatErrorMessage(const unsigned int cnError)
{
    char pszError[MAX_STRLEN] = "Описание ошибки отсутствует";
    try
    {
        int nLen = (int) FormatMessageA(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
            NULL,
            cnError,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
            pszError,
            MAX_STRLEN,
            NULL
        );
        // FormatMessage записывает \r\n в конец строки и завершает строку нулём...
        while(--nLen >= 0 && (pszError[nLen] == '\r' || 
            pszError[nLen] == '\n' || pszError[nLen] == '\0'))
            pszError[nLen] = '\0';
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    return pszError;
}

// ставлю кириллицу в консоли

void SetConsole(const wchar_t *pszTitle = NULL, BOOL bFullScreen = FALSE)
{
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font;
    HANDLE hStdOut = NULL;

    // кодовая страница
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    // шрифт
    font.cbSize = sizeof font;
    font.nFont = 1;
    font.dwFontSize = { 9, 18 };
    font.FontFamily = 0 | FF_DONTCARE & ~TMPF_FIXED_PITCH;
    font.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    wcscpy_s(font.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE, L"Lucida Console");

    // установка шрифта
    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdOut, FALSE, &font))
        printf("SetConsole: ошибка! Невозможно установить шрифт: %s.\n", FormatErrorMessage(GetLastError()).c_str());

    // заголовок и полный экран...
    if (pszTitle)
        SetConsoleTitleW(pszTitle);
    if (bFullScreen)
//      SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

затем над своей ф-цией `main` так запиши:

```
void SetConsole(const wchar_t *pszTitle = NULL, BOOL bFullScreen = FALSE);
```

а в `main` перед обращением к объектам ввода/вывода вызови эту функцию примерно так:

```
SetConsole(L"Заголовок окна", TRUE);
```

В вызове первый аргумент - строка из двухбайтовых символов (константа начинается с `'L'`), которая будет отображаться в заголовке консоли, а второй аргумент, если `TRUE`, будет разворачивать консоль в её максимальный размер.

Ввод кириллицы включается установкой кодовой страницы `1251` и заменой шрифта на `Lucida Console`. Шрифт можно и вручную поменять.