# из ASCII в UTF-8 C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, ascii

Здравствуйте. Работаю с архивами: создание, добавление элементов и т.д..

Такая проблема: сторонний метод принимает имя элемента или архива const char*, если имя содержит русские символы, то работает не правильно.

Конвертирую в Utf8, работает, но делаю это через wstring(пока тестирую), который не знаю как заполнять снаружи, например из консоли или какого-нибудь пользовательского интерфейса.

Можно ли обойтись без wstring или заполнять wstring снаружи?

Консоль здесь ни при чём.

Пример того, что делаю я:

```
std::wstring zipName = L"C:\\Users\\malenkov\\Desktop\\Test\\маша.zip";

/// Конвертация
inline std::string ToUtf8(const std::wstring& str)
{
    static std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> Utf8conv;
    return Utf8conv.to_bytes(str);
}
/// Создание архива
zip_t* zipArchive = ::zip_open(ToUtf8(zipName).c_str(), ZIP_CREATE, &error);
```

И вот я хочу узнать: как можно задать zipName в рантайме, ведь без wstring, как я понимаю, не обойтись.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: У меня проблема не с консолью. Я работаю с архивом. И дело в именах архива и его элементов.

Comment: Если решения в упомянутой теме Вам не помогли, приведите [mcve] и внесите изменения в тело вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос в том, в какой кодировке функция _ожидает_ строку. Если ответ «ни в какой, строка себе и строка, а чё», то у вас проблема.

Comment: Я, конечно, в этом не специалист, но похоже это обычный ASCII, раз кириллица не работает.

Comment: Консоль я написал для примера. Также я указал пользовательский интерфейс, чтобы не заострять внимание на консоли. Для приложения будет написан GUI, но также она будет получать команды через именованные каналы от других программ. Задать я имею в виду, что-то типа cin для string, но через wcin не получается, ведь он принимает int...

Comment: С кодом понятнее. Я вам предлагаю два варианта 1. рукописный - конвертируйте ASCII в UTF8 вручную, можно даже найти в нете. Может есть встроена функция конвертации ASCII-Utf8. 2. перекодируйте ASCII в WCHAR а потом вызовите ToUtf8, можно даже совместить две функции так `std::string ToUtf8(char * str){ wchar_t str2[1024/*max*/]; wsprintfW(str2,"%hs", str); return ToUtf8(str2); };`

Comment: Попробую ваш способ, спасибо. Сообщу о результатах.

Comment: По хорошему нужно проверить длинну строки, сделать malloc, потом free, много мороки. Я в таких случаях конвертирую именно как написал, а число /*max*/ подбираю по-случаю. Ещё это для windows

Comment: А wsprintfW будет работать под Linux? Забыл написать, что программа должна быть кроссплатформенная.

Comment: Если хочется в 1 строку - `boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(text, locale);`

Comment: @nick_n_a Всё получилось, спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: 1- каждая ascii строка является utf-8 строкой (utf-8 специально так был создан) 2- можно везде текст как utf-8 байты хранить (в `char*`, `string`) внутри программы, а на границе преобразовывать то что система даёт, например, для ввода/вывода через стандартные потоки в кроссплатформенном коде [можно nowide::cin/cout потоки попробовать, которые автоматически конвертируют utf-8 строки в `wchar_t` строки, если необходимо для Windows Unicode API](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044)—на других системах это обычные std::cin/cout.

Comment: ASCII является подмножеством UTF-8. Вы видимо про что-то другое хотели спросить.

Answer (score 1):

> Такая проблема: сторонний метод принимает имя элемента или архива const char*, если имя содержит русские символы, то работает не правильно.
>
> Конвертирую в Utf8, работает, но делаю это через wstring(пока тестирую), который не знаю как заполнять снаружи, например из консоли или какого-нибудь пользовательского интерфейса.

Это говорит только о том, что сторонний метод ждет UTF-8, представленное в виде массива 8-битных символов (const char*).

> Консоль здесь ни при чём.

Сама консоль возможно не причем (хотя как сказать), а вот какая локаль выставлена - это существенно. Это определяет в каком именно виде будут переданы вводимые данные в рантайме. Например, если вы вводите строку из консоли, работающей в локали ru_RU.CP1251 - то прилетят 8-битные символы, если ru_RU.UTF-8 - на вход прилетит уже сформированная UTF-8 строка.

Таким образом, задача сводится к шагам:

- Выяснить в каком виде (в какой локали) производиться ввод данных
- Если 8-битный ввод, предварительно преобразовать в UTF-8
- Если UTF-8 - просто передать введенное

**Но есть важные замечания**

Первое

UI предназначается для работы с символами, а не с кодами символов! Что это значит? В различных 8-битовых кодировках (в расширенной части 128-255) определены собственные символы, которые могут отсутствовать в "соседних" 8-битных кодировках. Поэтому "почти" однозначное преобразование возможно только в одном направлении ASCII->UTF-8. Почему "почти"? Например, если взять символы кириллицы, то символ с кодом 0x98 из cp1251 - не имеет аналога ни в Unicode, ни в UTF-8.

Второе

"Широкие символы" в стандарте Unicode 4.0 (ISO/IEC 10646:2003) определяются как compiler-specific, и могут быть даже 8-ми битными. Поэтому, дабы подстраховаться от потерь при преобразованиях, я бы посоветовал вместо std::wstring использовать [std::u32string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u32string/)

Третье

Используя STL, конечно же, лучше всего использовать предоставляемые средства перекодировок, это обеспечит большую кроссплатформенность кода. И, тем не менее, если программа должна обеспечивать наиболее полный набор UTF-8, включая разнообразные иероглифические кодировки, можно глянуть внешнюю библиотеку [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Четвертое

Для работы сугубо с кириллицей можно попробовать написать свои процедуры перекодировок. Для C++ я не вижу необходимости. Хотя для чистого Си, в принципе можно. Ниже представлю таблицу, которую собирал по различным стандартам из [unicode.org](http://unicode.org) которую в данный момент собираюсь использовать для написания собственной библиотеки для Lua.

Comment: Я, например, автор, хочу сделать копипаст - оно работает.  Можно привести рабочий пример?

Comment: @nick_n_a, для данного вопроса копипасты быть не может - т.к. не все условия оговорены. А именно - в какой кодировке предполагается ввод. Автоматически определение так достоверно невозможно - метод ввода не обозначен. Например, читаем STDIN. Да, можно определить текущую локаль (если она есть), но данные могут быть введены через pipe, в совершенно другой кодировке. Поэтому и мой ответ не предполагает наличие кода.