# таблица сиволов ascii в языке си. Как вывести символ копирайта - © .

Tags: c, ascii, авторские-права

char принимает диапазон от -127 до 128. Символ копирайта имеет код 169 из таблицы ascii, то есть не входит в диапазон типа char. Вопрос как вывести символ копирайта, и почему он не входит в диапазон?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571405/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> char принимает диапазон от -127 до 128

Зависит от компилятора :)

> Символ копирайта имеет код 169 из таблицы ascii

Во-первых, в какой кодировке? В 866 там "й", например... Во-вторых, ASCII заканчивается кодом 127.

Просто присваивайте и выводите. Преобразование пройдет как надо. Но нужно еще указать, что вывод осуществляется в кодировке 1251.

Comment: _**Но нужно еще указать, что вывод осуществляется в кодировке 1251.**_ . Как можно это сделать подскажите?

Comment: Что-то никак не найду, как это в `setlocale` правильно указать... Но, например, `system("chcp 1251 > null");` :-) Или - включить `<windows.h>` и вызвать `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);`