# Почему не выводится текст после русского языка и только латиница до этого c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Используя `wstring` и `wchar_t` в c++, возникла проблема вывода промежуточной информации в консоль. Кодировка проекта стоит UTF-8. Если поменять на UTF-16, то проблема останется, но ещё добавятся иероглифы.

```
wcout << L"Text"; // Выводится нормально.
wcout << L"Текст на русском"; // Не выводится.
wcout << L"Text"; // Не выводится, хотя уже английские буквы.
cout << "Выводится"; // cout работает нормально.
```

Есть использовать `cout`, то всё хорошо, но данные у меня хранятся в `wchar_t` и `wstring` поэтому `cout` не подходит.

Библиотека `windows.h` на mac os недоступна, поэтому `SetConsoleSp` и пр. не подходят. `setlocale` тоже не помогла.

Я пытался менять шрифт и кодировки, комбинировать их, но ничто не помогает.

P.S. Я понимаю, что похожие вопросы по выводу в консоль уже были, но следуя тем инструкциям у меня не получилось сделать читаемый результат для обработки и вывода в консоль.

Тестовый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main() {

wcout << L"Text" << endl;
wcout << L"Русский текст" << endl;
wcout << L"Text" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

На выходе(терминал mac os) только слово Text.

Comment: А какая платформа и компилятор?

Comment: IDE - `CLion` от `Jetbrains`.
Компилятор - `CMake` (там из `xcode`'a)

Comment: А какая у вас ОС? Мак? Должно по идее проходить общелинуксовское решение.

Comment: @VladD Mac Os Sierra

Comment: @VladD Но хотелось бы, чтобы и под винду всё без перекомпиляции/замены кодировки прошло.

Comment: У винды поддержка локалей никакая. Поэтому придется разделять реализации для винды отдельно, для *nix отдельно.

Comment: @Majestio: У винды прекрасная поддержка кодировок, а вот с юниксовскими локалями она и вправду не очень дружит. И консоль в ней слабовата (главным образом потому, что никому, кроме программистов, не нужна).

Comment: Вот [переносимый код на C++, который позволяет Unicode на разных системах печатать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044). Чтобы начать осваиваться с  Unicode, прочтя одну страницу http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @VladD , на счет кодировок в винде - не спорю ни разу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
// в вашем случае, аналогично вашему последнему варианту
// за исключением того, что кодировка строкового литерала
// указывается явно

cout << u"Текст на русском";
```

Только в вопросе не указана кодировка (точнее локаль) в терминале, а это существенно.

Для конвертации `std::wstring` в `std::string` (для `UTF8`) советуют:

```
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
  return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

**Дополнение**

Пример работающего модифицированного кода (проверялось под `macOS Sierra 10.12.3`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>

std::string wtos(const std::wstring& str) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
  return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::wstring& str) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
  stream << myconv.to_bytes(str);
  return stream;
}

int main() {
  std::wstring S1 = L"Text";
  std::wstring S2 = L"Русский текст";
  std::wstring S3 = L"Text";
  // Вариант вывода через функцию
  std::cout << wtos(S1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << wtos(S2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << wtos(S3) << std::endl;
  // Вариант вывода через перегрузку оператора <<
  std::cout << S1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << S2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << S3 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Выводит:

```
Text
Русский текст
Text
Text
Русский текст
Text
```

Comment: после русского текста таким `cout`'ом вывело вот это: `0x10c5c1e8c` (должно быть `"text"`, без кавычек);

Comment: Какая локаль в вашем терминале?

Comment: Немного не понял и у меня нет codevt_utf8 в std.

Comment: В терминале наберите `locale` и покажите вывод этой команды.

Comment: `LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=` - вывод терминала.
Но, возможно встроенный терминал в IDE по-другому как-то работает.

Comment: Попробуйте собрать и запустить в "живом" терминале, а не в эмуляторе IDE.

Comment: Проблема осталась.
В `vim` написал следующее:
`using namespace std;

int main() {
    wcout << L"Text" << endl;
    wcout << L"Русский текст" << endl;
    wcout << L"Text" << endl;
    return 0;
}`
Но на выходе в родном терминале получил: `Text`

Comment: По поводу `codevt_utf8`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8 может заголовок не был включен `#include <codecvt>`

Comment: В вопросе опубликуйте свой тестовый код, в комментах он нечитаем.

Comment: Добавил тестовый код

Comment: @kot_mapku3 , дополнил свой ответ работающим кодом.

Comment: Можно только вас попросить, пожалуйста, пример перегрузки для wchar_t вывода, т.к. без неё он выводит код символа.

Comment: Для корректного вывода `wchar_t` нужно его сперва сконвертировать в `std::string`. Как это сделать - можно почитать тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339960/how-do-i-convert-wchar-t-to-stdstring

Comment: Ну, я сделал так: `wstring(1, wchar_t)`. Спасибо!