# Проблема с получением списка файлов С++

Tags: c++, windows

Имеется проблема с получением списка файлов. Функция выполняется. Но на определенном моменте просто стопорится. И все.

```
int main(){
catalogs ctlss;
catalogs * ctls = &ctlss;
int length = 0;
int * len = &length;
STRSAFE_LPWSTR dir = L"C:";
toms t;
toms * tm = &t;
get_toms(tm);
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    std::wcout << "CYCLE_DISK: " << t.names[i] << std::endl;
     }
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    get_paths_arguments(t.names[i], ctls, len);
     }
for (int i = 0; i < ctls->length; i++) {
    std::wcout << "LENGTH: " << ctls->length << std::endl;
    std::wcout << ctls->catls[i].name;
    std::wcout.flush();
    }
}
int get_paths_arguments(STRSAFE_LPWSTR dir, catalogs * ctls, int *len)
    {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t length_of_arg;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    std::wcout << dir << std::endl;
    StringCchLength(dir, MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);
    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, dir);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));
    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    do
    {
        std::wcout << L"dir + cFileName: " <<std::wstring(dir) + std::wstring(ffd.cFileName) << std::endl;
        try {
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (!(std::wstring(L".") == std::wstring(ffd.cFileName)) && !(std::wstring(L"..") == std::wstring(ffd.cFileName))) {
                    std::wstring line = dir + std::wstring(L"\\") + std::wstring(ffd.cFileName);
                    std::wcout << L"DIR_LINE: " << line << std::endl;
                    STRSAFE_LPWSTR direct = dir + *ffd.cFileName;
                    get_paths_arguments((STRSAFE_LPWSTR)line.c_str(), ctls, len);
                }
                else {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ctls->catls[*len].name = std::wstring(dir) + std::wstring(L"\\") + std::wstring(ffd.cFileName);
                *len = *len + 1;
                ctls->length = *len;
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception &e) {
            std::wcout << L"EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd));

    dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);
return 0;
    }
```

Задача состоит в том что бы получить рекурсивно все файлы и папки на диске.
При этом некоторые строки даже не допечатываются до конца. Просто все останавливается и консоль ждет завершения процессов. И ничего больше не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, В чем может быть причина?

Comment: 1. Что выводит ваша программа? 2. Если во время повисания нажать паузу, то в каком месте находиться выполнение программы. У вас скорее всего бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Программа выводит на экран имена файлов. Цикл продолжается до тех пор пока не будут выведены все файлы на носителе. Условие выполнения цикла вот do{//цикл}while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd));

Comment: можно попробовать `<filesystem>` использовать, чтобы рекурсивно папки обойти ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)) и `boost::nowide`, чтобы [Unicode в консоль вывести переносимо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wcout стопорит вывод в консоль, если в строке попадается символ отличный от латиницы. "test" выведет, "тест" уже нет. Варианты:

1. сначала задать std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
2. предварительно перевести wchar_t в char
3. использовать функцию WriteConsoleW

Comment: Так и сделал. Действительно проблема была в этом. Спасибо большое.