# Вывод в консоль кирилицы

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Каким образом прочитать данные(и вывести в консоль), чтобы строка была нормальной без escape символов и чтобы отдельные слова не заменялись кодировкой байт, например Подключе\u00ADие. В чем вообще проблема?

```
    #include <QCoreApplication>
    #include <QProcess>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QTextCodec>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        QProcess *console = new QProcess();

        QStringList aList;

        console->start( "ipconfig" );

        QByteArray aOut;
        if( console->waitForFinished( ) == true )
        {
            aOut = console->readAllStandardOutput();
        }

        QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName( "Windows-1251" );
        QString sOut = codec->toUnicode( aOut );

        qDebug() << sOut;

        return a.exec();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте конвертировать вот так `QString sOut = codec->toUnicode( QString(aOut).toLocal8Bit() );` - это немножко поможет.

Comment: KoVadim к сожалению не помогло, теперь вместо кирилических букв вопросительные знаки

Comment: я пока не могу проверить - у меня только англоязычные винды... А на англоязычных все ок. Может там все таки кодировка 866, а не cp1251?

Comment: KoVadim cp-866 кракозябры выводит

Comment: да, да, все правильно. и должны они быть. выводите не на консоль, а файл и открывайте блокнотом (или его заменителями). Вы читаете с консоли, которая 866 и потом пытались это преобразовать cp1251->unicode. Это получалось частично (что собственно Вы и видели). В последнем случае увидели "крякозяблы", потому что это так выглядит юникод, распечатанный на 866.

Comment: KoVadim Попробовал в файл, все работает! Спасибо! Отвечайте на вопрос поставлю галку как решение. Хотя было бы неплохо разобраться как и в консоль без "кракозябр" выводить.

Comment: связанный вопрос [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571405/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Терминал в винде (если никто ничего не трогал), работает в кодировке 866. Она отлична от кодировок cp1251 и юникода. В своем оригинальном коде Вы пытаетесь декодировать 866 кодировку как cp1251 в юникод (это уже интересно) и результат выводите на экран, где он интерпретируется как 866. Скорее всего, преобразование прошло частично и только повредило некоторые символы, и вывод удался (почти).

Благодаря Майкрософту, который со всех сил пытается делать суперсовместимость, внутри винды живет несколько несовместимых кодировок, о которых нужно помнить. Терминал работает в 866 (старая досовская кодировка). Qt  в основном использует юникод (как и ядро современной винды). cp1251 используют в основном старые программы и сейчас она потихоньку отходит в мир иной.

Поэтому, скорее всего, что бы работать правильно, нужно весь ввод конвертировать себе в юникод. А когда нужно вывести - конвертировать в 866 назад.