# Считываю в строку из html-файла - записывается мусор вместо русских букв

Tags: html, c++, кодировка, utf-8, getline

Нужно считать с html файла строку, и дальше сделать какие-то действия, но проблема в том, что в строку вместо русских букв считывается из файла мусор. С другими файлами всегда все было нормально. Проблема, думаю, именно в файле. Пытался делать

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Пытался

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

Ничего не помогает. html-файл взял путем сохранения страницы вручную. С остальными файлами проблем нет, проблема только с файлами формата .html
[image: Наглядно показано, что мусор выводится и на консоль, и в строку]

Считываю из файла так:

```
getline(FileStreamOut, ParseStr)
```

Как сделать, чтобы записывались русские символы нормально в строку?

Comment: Какие типы имеют `FileStreamOut` и `ParseStr`?

Comment: ifstream и string

Comment: [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring), [codecvt_utf8](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)

Comment: то есть вы пытаетесь вывести текст в utf-8 кодировке в консоль через API,  которое вероятно cp866 кодировку ожидает, при этом вы почему то на cp1251 хотите кодировку поменять. Не удивительно что краеозчбры получаются. Чтобы текст в консоль выводить, можно использовать Unicode. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте на самой html странице указать кодировку UTF-8 через meta тег:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
уже есть эта строка, да и вручную что-то прописывать в файле - не выход