# Надстрочные и подстрочные знаки язык C

Tags: c

Возможно ли функцией printf отображать подстрочные и надстрочные знаки? Например если надо отобразить на экране вот такую запись
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотря какой инструмент визуализации вы используете. В юникодах 2 - верхний индекс например существует - вы можете просто его вывести. В ANSI char[] нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a `char[]` это последовательность байтов, которая может представлять текст в любой кодировке.

Comment: @jfs Точно. Я не подумал, ну тогда если найти кодировку в которой есть верхние и нижние цифры в пределе 128...255 - и переключить на нёё - то отобразить можно.

Comment: В первую очередь, к этому должен быть готов терминал

Comment: Ответ - теоретически возможно, если выводить их в кодовой странице 2070—209F  http://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/superscripts-and-subscripts/

Comment: Функция `printf` ничего не "отображает на экране". Функция `printf` только записывает последовательность символов в стандартный текстовый выходной поток. А уж в каком виде этот поток предстанет перед вашими глазами (если вообще предстанет) зависит только от свойств и настроек того средства отображения, через которое вы будете рассматривать содержимое этого потока. Вот от этого и надо отталкиваться.

Comment: Можно с помощью printf печатать HTML или какой-нибудь LaTeX и на ходу отображать любой подходящей программой :D

Answer (score 3):

Если терминал настроен на utf-8 кодировку и шрифт поддерживает соответствующие символы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf(u8"(X\u2081 - X\u2082)\u00b2 + (Y\u2081 - Y\u2082)\u00b2\n");
}
```

Пример:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 *.c && ./a.out
(X₁ - X₂)² + (Y₁ - Y₂)²
```

[На Windows, `wprintf()` можно использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044). Вот [переносимое решение на C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044).

Comment: Красиво:) Сам не ожидал:)

Answer (score 2):

В `utf-8`терминале можно даже так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("(X₁ - X₂)²+(Y₁ - Y₂)²\n");
    // Или printf(u8"(X₁ - X₂)²+(Y₁ - Y₂)²\n"); с -std=c11

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
sh-4.2$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                                                                         
sh-4.2$ main                                                                                                                                                    
(X₁ - X₂)²+(Y₁ - Y₂)²
```

[Fiddle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUHFWbnhEWTRMakU)

Comment: нет никакой гарантии, что компилятор байты в utf-8 сохранит: [Is the u8 string literal necessary in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13444930/4279)

Comment: Вот никогда не имел с этим проблем. Мб, из-за отсутствия зоопарка компиляторов? Но, возьму на заметку)

Comment: Основной посыл ответа был в том, что в utf-8 исходнике сами символы представляют более читаемый эквивалент `\uxxxx` последовательности.