# Какие то непонятные символы после запуска программы

Tags: c

Всем привет. Использую редактор *Clion*. После успешной компиляции программы при запуске выводит непонятные символы:

> ╨▓╨▓╨╡╨┤╨╕╤В╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╖╨▓╨░╨╜╨╕╨╡ ╨║╨░╤А╤В╤Л

Я уже понял, что проблема в кодировке, но какую кодировку выбирать, чтобы не было таких косяков?

Вот код на всякий случай:

```
int main() {
      char card_name[3];
      puts("введите название карты ");
      scanf("%2s", card_name);
      int val = 0;
      if(card_name[0] == 'K'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if(card_name[0] == 'Q'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if (card_name[0] == 'J'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if(card_name[0] == 'A'){
          val = 11;
      }   else {
          val = atoi(card_name);
      }
      printf("Ценность карты: %i\n", val);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Похожие письмена оставляют инопланетяне: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RirqnBUQTEU Декодировать послания можно при помощи их технологии: https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/ А из астрала мне сообщают, что если поставить кодировку файла как cp866, то вы обретете дар чтения этих загадочных символов.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Как отобразить русский текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему так происходит?

CLion по дефолту использует UTF-8 для хранения файлов с исходным кодом. Строка "Привет, Мир!" будет представлять собой последовательность (в файле с исходником):

D0 9F D1 80 D0 B8 D0 B2 D0 B5 D1 82 2C 20 D0 9C D0 B8 D1 80 21
Как видите, на 12 символов исходной строки, получили 21 байт (т.к. кириллические символы занимают больше одного байта).

Компилятор GCC по умолчанию читает исходники в кодировке UTF8, если не указать другую через ключ -finput-charset. Таким образом эта последовательность байтов в неизменном виде сохранится в исполняемый файл.

При запуске программы на исполнение, CLion использует стандартный cmd.exe, который по умолчанию скорей всего у вас работает в кодировке CP866. В которой наша последовательность байтов будет отображена как:

╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В, ╨Ь╨╕╤А!
(что вы и видите в терминале CLion)

Что делать?

Вариант 1

Сменить кодировку файла на IBM866 (то же, что и CP866) (настройки - File Encodings) (сам файл перекодировать, если там уже был текст на русском). Теперь кириллица будет сохраняться в файле с исходным текстом в кодировке CP866 (один байт на символ), в том же виде попадать в исполняемый файл и нормально отображаться в консоли CLion. Разумеется, использовать CP866 в 17-м году, без особых на то оснований, это некультурно. Кроме того придется ограничить себя только символами из CP866.

Вариант 2

Вставить в начало свой программы:

system("chcp 65001");
или (потребует #include ):

SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
Консоль переключится в UTF-8, все будет отображаться как надо. Но только при использовании низкоуровневых операций вывода типа puts("Привет, Мир!");. Если выводить через std::cout, то возможен вывод типа ��ривет, Мир!. Это связано с тем, что Windows API для вывода в консоль ожидает видеть в каждом вызове законченную строку. И если оператор basic_ostream::operator<<(char*) для символа 'П' выполнит два API вызова (с  D0 и 9F), то они не сольются в одну букву 'П', а будут интерпретированы и отображены как два разных символа (��).

Предостережение

При использовании UTF-8 в своей программе, например при хранении в std::string, следует помнить, что операции над строками могут дать не очевидные результаты (т.к. один символ теперь может занимать от 1 до 4 байтов).

Кроме вывода, аналогичные проблемы ожидают и при вводе из std::cin. Таким образом, единственное прозрачное решение для Windows (даже десятки), пока остается использование латиницы.

Comment: Зачем копировать чужой ответ?

Comment: @Sv__t так как он правильный

Comment: @Sv__t я уже отметил свой вопрос как дубликат

Comment: по ссылке из вопроса можно перейти к ответу

Answer (score 0):

Переключите консоль на `UTF-8`:

```
int main() {
      system("chcp 65001"); // Устанавливаем UTF-8
      char card_name[3];
      puts("введите название карты ");
      scanf("%2s", card_name);
      int val = 0;
      if(card_name[0] == 'K'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if(card_name[0] == 'Q'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if (card_name[0] == 'J'){
          val = 10;
      }   else if(card_name[0] == 'A'){
          val = 11;
      }   else {
          val = atoi(card_name);
      }
      printf("Ценность карты: %i\n", val);
      return 0;
}
```