# Проблема с выводом на консоль всех символов кодировки cp1251

Tags: c, кодировка, cp1251

Программа должна выводить на консоль все символы кодировки cp1251 в таком формате: "[код символа] - [символ]". 
Написал сначала цикл, который выводит первые 128 символов этой кодировки (то бишь все символы ASCII) - в условии цикла было "i < 127", программа работала правильно и вывела список всех символов. Но после того, как я изменил условие на "i < 255", программа после запуска стала выводить список бесконечно (я сделал два скрина пока она бешенно его выводила). Не могу понять, в чём проблема.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    for(char i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        printf("%i - %c\n", (int)i, i);


    return  0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: помимо unsigned, попробуйте wprintf. [Как отобразить русский текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` - он может быть и знаковым, и беззнаковым - зависит от компилятора. Если он знаковый - то он всегда будет меньше 255...

Попробуйте

```
for(unsigned char i = 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно в этом проблема. И да, с условием ещё налажал, должно быть i <= 255.

Comment: А, нет, с "i <= 255" цикл опять бесконечный. С "i < 255" всё нормально. Буду читать матчасть.

Comment: Ну сами посудите с i <= 255 - ведь i никак не может стать равным 256 :) Если ответ решил проблему - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Comment: Почитал про signed и unsigned char, всё понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

8-битный тип char не подходит для перебора всех 256 значений, поскольку не будет такого значения, которое не соответствовало бы условию остановки цикла. Для этих целей лучше использовать int. Но для перебора только печатных символов в диапазоне 32-255 всё таки можно, и делается это так - `for(i=32;i;i++) /* do something */;`

Comment: И все же `char uc = 0;   do { printf("%u ", uc++ & 0xff); } while (uc);` пробегает **все 256** значений -)